# formula in excel to count info in three columns, but one of the three criteria is only if it's within a certain range

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a formula to count several criteria, but exclude others. For example, I have a list with three years worth of data - I want to find the value of something that only happened in december of 2017 and then from that sum, the value of how many are male. Every formula I've tried ends up counting too much or too little... 
I tried the following and I'm not getting right!

```
=Countifs(B1:Q37, "December", B1:B37, "2017", B1:Q37, "male")
```

also this:

```
=COUNTIF(Hires!B1:Q37, "December&2017")+COUNTIF(Hires!B1:Q37, "male")
```

I also tried this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Hires!B1:Q37, "December", Hires!B1:Q37, 
            "=2017") + COUNTIF(Hires!B1:Q37, "male"))
```

How do i condition it to count if and only if?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your data?

Comment: When using COUNTIFS() your criteria ranges must all be of the same size.  Do you have a YEAR column, a MONTH column and a SEX column in your data?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you share some data, the result of what you've tried so far, and your expected result.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, the criteria range is all the same size, with year, month and gender information..

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A37, "December", B1:B37, "2017", C1:C37, "male")
```

Assuming ColA has month, ColB has year, and ColC has sex (adjust to suit your actual data).

Comment: Thanks - I tried this originally (see my original comment) - the problem I'm having is that it's counting all the males in all the months of 2017- not just the ones in december. Is there a way to countif and only if?

Comment: You'll need to share a screenshot of your data (or something similar to your data) if what I posted doesn't work

Comment: I just noticed what I did wrong - and how you did it differently! I was counting the whole entire database for each requirement instead of only counting the columns separately as the range and then my specific criteria for that. Thank you for your help!!!